# How to view all Unicode characters assigned to keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

How can I see what characters are assigned to various key combinations on my keyboard? For example, I found out that if I press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>, I'm getting an "m-dash" character: "—". I would like to know all other characters I can get, without having to test them one by one in an editor! Especially given the fact, that some are "combining characters", which makes them even more difficult to test.